# Video not working on mobile safari

Tags: wordpress, safari, html5-video, mobile-safari

My video mp4, Webm format are not working on safari mobile ( video on autoplay ) using wordpress with a theme called avada.
[This is what the video looks like on mobile safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNzuU.jpg)

Comment: autoplay will not work on mobile safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the html and css output that the WordPress theme generates?

Autoplay videos didn't work on mobile iOS previous to iOS 10, and in order to get video to autoplay on iOS 10, the
    playsinline
attribute must be added to the video element like so :

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline poster="images/poster.jpg" class="fullscreen-video">
<source src="video/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video/vid.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

The muted attribute is necessary to play on mobile Android Chrome, and the playsinline attribute will make the above autoplay on mobile Safari on iOS 10 (but not previous versions of iOS).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the code generated by the theme : <video preload="auto" autoplay="" loop="" muted=""><source src="video/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hd.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="video/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hd.webm" type="video/webm"></video>

Comment: How can i add the changes to the HTML generated by the theme ?

Comment: This is the css added to the class : position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 1;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

Comment: You likely can't edit the source code unless you want to get into editing PHP.

Most WordPress templates will allow you to enter direct HTML code as a content block, and you can paste the above code, modifying it to call the sources of your video and poster image (which isn't required)

For the HTML video element above, start with a very basic CSS for the fullscreen-video class like this:

    .fullscreen-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }

That is how I add HTML5 autoplay video into WordPress sites that don't support it natively.

Comment: Thx for your help

Comment: Sure. If that answer proved correct, feel free to mark it as the approved answer.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, how can i mark it as approved ?

Comment: Thanks! Here's a [link with instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for marking answers as approved.